# Script has different behavior on different systems

Tags: netbeans, ant

I have the **default generated** ant script for my netbeans java project and it works great on my windows desktop, I got my *dist* folder with the *lib* folder inside.
Now I have the same files and folders on a debian system and run ant, but the *dist* folder never contains the dependency jars in the *lib* folder.

The settings in the project and so on are correct.

I am using ant 1.8.0 with debian 6.0.3 and ant 1.8.2 with windows xp.

Here is the ant script generated by netbeans http://pastebin.com/dk2x8Na1.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the "mistake":

I compared the log files and found the problem:

> -do-jar-with-libraries-pack:
>   Skipped because property 'do.mkdist' not set.

You can find in the file *build.xml* following:

```
<condition property="do.mkdist">
    <and>
        <isset property="do.archive"/>
        <isset property="libs.CopyLibs.classpath"/>
        <not>
            <istrue value="${mkdist.disabled}"/>
        </not>
    </and>
</condition>
```

It seems that **libs.CopyLibs.classpath** isn't set. There is an implementation from NetBeans, which you can find it here *java/ant/extra*. The lib is called *org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar*.
I added to my *project.properties* the following entry:

```
libs.CopyLibs.classpath=tools/org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar
```

After that all works fine with Debian, too.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience of developing on a Windows environment and then deploying on Linux, there are a few things that could be the problem:

1. The use of paths: Always rather use /Temp/application/alpha rather
   than C:\Temp\application\alpha - A forward slash / is equivalent to
   a double back-slash \ on Windows and is compatible on Linux
2. Check that the version of Java on Linux is the same and is also 32/64 as your Windows Java version is.
3. Ensure that any 3rd party jars are included in your Linux Java version e.g. security encryption upgrades etc.
4. Your global path is correctly set.  Especially when running cron jobs.
5. Try and use the java environment variables where possible.  For example when referencing the temp folder use ${java.io.tmpdir}.

I have tried to answer your question with very little info.

Would you be able to provide your ant script?

Comment: The ant script is about 60 KB and it is really the default netbeans script, I haven't edited anything. You can find the script above.